# How mutual exclusion works?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to understand how mutual exclusion theory works.

[image]

It says

When such a linked list is being shared between multiple threads of execution, two threads of execution may attempt to remove two different nodes simultaneously, one thread of execution changing the next pointer of node `i-1` to point to node `i+1`, while another thread of execution changes the next pointer of node `i` to point to node `i+2`.

Confused here:

Although both removal operations complete successfully, the desired state of the linked list is not achieved: node i+1 remains in the list, because the next pointer of node i-1 points to node i+1.

```
the desired state of the linked list is not achieved
```

May I know what he's trying to say `"because the next pointer of node i-1 points to node i+1."` ? Couldn't understand.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  1) As far as I can see, the body of the question is not about mutual exclusion at all.  2) The description seems to be related to a specific implementation of "remove", but you haven't shown us the code of that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide, which I believe is outlined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), is missing some critical details.

- We have a shared resource `(i-1)->(i)->(i+1)->(i+2)`
- We have two threads of execution, lets call them `T1`, and `T2`, accessing the linked list as a shared resource simultaneously.
- `T1` removes node `(i)` at the same time `T2` removes node `(i + 1)`
- The resulting list would be `(i-1) -> (i+2)` had we performed these steps sequentially
- What we get instead is : `(i-1) -> (i+1) -> (i+2)`

Mutual Exclusion refers to the fact that one thread of execution should never enters its critical section at the same time that another concurrent thread of execution enters its own critical section.  In the above example, we would need to prevent both threads from mutating the same list at the same time, using some kind of synchronization primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a linked list

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

You tell thread 1 "Hey, remove B for me, ok?". At the same time, you tell thread 2 "Hey, can you remove C for me?".

The following then happens simultaneously:

- Thread 1 thinks "Okay, I want to remove B. That means I must make A point to C instead of B."
- Thread 2 thinks "Okay, I want to remove C. That means I must make B point to D instead of C."

The two threads are separate; they don't know what the other one is doing. As such, they both believe their arguments make perfect sense. And they do, but only when nobody else is altering the list at the same time. The result ends up like this:

```
A -> C -> D
       B -^
```

A no longer points to B; it points to C instead. Likewise, B no longer points to C; it points to D instead.

...and since B is no longer reachable, it will be garbage collected, leaving this:

```
A -> C -> D
```

**We told one thread to remove B and another thread to remove C. B is gone, but C is still in the list. This is not what we expected; we expected only A and D to be left.**

This is a very simple example of how horribly wrong things can go when multiple threads modify the same data at the same time. You either need to use difficult tricks to make it work, or use "mutual exclusion", i.e. limiting modifications of the list to only one thread at a time.

Comment: Why C is still in the List ?